# How can I find the number of dissimilar or distinct terms in $(1+x + x^2 +x^3)^n$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How can I find the number of dissimilar or distinct terms in $(1+x + x^2 +x^3)^n$  ?

I know it would be $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$   when they are $a , b, c ,d$ instead of $1 , x , x^2 , x^3$.

But how can I do it for this case?
 Can anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Have you worked out how many there are in the cases $n=0,1,2,3$ ? Can't you spot the pattern? And then prove it?

Answer (score 1):

What's the highest degree monomial you can get? What's the lowest degree? Can you get the ones in between?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very good answer, but I suppose you asked for a hint.

When you say distinct terms I assume you are referring to the order of x. so:

$x^2 \ \ and \  \ 2x^2$

are not distinct, but:

$x^2 \ \ and \  \ 2x^3$

are distinct.

So you want to know the number of distinct terms in a polynomial. Unfortunately this polynomial is difficult to expand as we aren't sure what n is. Hopefully we can get an answer in terms of n.

Here is how I would attempt the problem: differentiate your polynomial, which means you lose your constant term (in this case its 1 regardless of what n is), so now you have 1 less distinct term than in your original polynomial. Now differentiate again, you have now lost your original linear terms, so you have 2 less distinct terms than in your original polynomial.

So maybe it is possible to figure out how many times do you need to differentiate this polynomial (as a function of n) before it becomes zero. I think that number will be how many distinct terms you have.

You will need the product rule and the chain rule, and will probably require some summation notation. Good luck!

Comment: Hmmmm, I suppose this only tells you the order of the highest term. Sorry! But because your polynomial has a 1 in it I suppose you can get every term from order 0 up to the highest order. I guess this is what @inavda means.